# multi threaded graphics using a timer?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer, java-2d

My lecturer gave me an assignment asking for a multi threaded graphics program where a ball bounces around a jframe. He wanted each ball to have its own thread. Upon marking he told me that a timer is multi threaded and this is the best way to do this. I used a new Thread for each ball I know this is costly but he told us to use a thread for each ball. Is the timer class multi threaded?

using a timer

```
Ball b = new Ball(x, y);
BallMover bm = new BallMover(b)//adds the ball to a new instance of an actionListner
theTimer.addActionListener(bm);
```

using threads

```
Ball b = new Ball(x,y);
BallMover bm = new BallMover(b);//adds the ball to a new instance of a Thread
bm.start();
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: not an SSCCE, probably everything here could be shorts to the dark only, up to you

Answer (score 2):

From the docs for the Swing [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

> Although all `Timers` perform their waiting using a single, shared thread (created by the first `Timer` object that executes), the action event handlers for `Timers` execute on another thread -- the event-dispatching thread. This means that the action handlers for `Timers` can safely perform operations on Swing components. However, it also means that the handlers must execute quickly to keep the GUI responsive.

Comment: so am I right in thinking that if I had 6 Balls each with there own ActionListener each actionPreformed method is running in its own thread? Thanks for the reply

Comment: no issue by using only one Swing Timer and with Arrays of Balls